# Does opencv or other libraries provide I422(YUV422 Planar) picture format support?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, yuv, image-formats

Currently I'm working with some YUV422p-formatted pics. I read the documentations and tried running python codes below:

```
print([i for i in dir(cv2) if i.startswith("COLOR_YUV")])
```

And I found no support for YUV422p format. Does anybody know the reason why opencv has no support for such format, or if there is any other python-based libraries that provides such support?

Comment: There is no in-built support, have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889484/opencv-convert-rgb-array-to-yuv422-in-python)

Comment: But what is the file format ? (Tiff, Png ?) If the image is already in memory, consider COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUYV.

Answer (score 0):

We may use [PyAV](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV) library.
PyAV is a Pythonic binding for the [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) libraries.

FFmpeg supports YUV422 Planar picture format, and PyAV also supports it.
Unlike other FFmpeg bindings, PyAV is relatively low-level - instead of using FFmpeg CLI, it allows more low level functionalities that supported by the C interface of FFmpeg.

[libswscale](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__libsws.html) is "sub module" of FFmpeg that supports multiple color formats conversions.
PyAV exposes some of the capabilities of libswscale.

---

Start by creating raw input file in yuv422p pixel format, using FFmpeg CLI.

Execute the following shell command for building sample input (used for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -vf "scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv" -pix_fmt yuv422p -f rawvideo input.yuv422p`

---

The next example, uses PyAV for converting from raw yuv422p to BGR pixel format:

- Create a `VideoFrame` object:

  ```
   frame = VideoFrame(cols, rows, 'yuv422p')
  ```
- Assume `y`, `u` and `v` are 3 color planes (`y` is full resolution, and `u` and `v` are half resolution in the horizontal axis).
  The planes may be stored in NumPy arrays or bytes arrays (multiple buffer formats are supported).
  Update the 3 planes of `frame`:

  ```
   frame.planes[0].update(y)
   frame.planes[1].update(u)
   frame.planes[2].update(v)
  ```

Convert the frame to BGR format using [reformat](https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/video.html#av.video.frame.VideoFrame.reformat) method, and convert to NumPy array:

```
    bgr_frame = frame.reformat(cols, rows, 'bgr24', src_colorspace='ITU709', dst_colorspace='DEFAULT', interpolation='BILINEAR')
    bgr = bgr_frame.to_ndarray()
```

---

The following code sample reads `yuv422p` raw data from file, converts to BRG using PyAV (and shows the output using OpenCV):

```
import cv2
from av.video.frame import VideoFrame

# Build raw input file using shell command:  
# ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -vf "scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv" -pix_fmt yuv422p -f rawvideo input.yuv422p

cols, rows, n_frames = 192, 108, 10

frame = VideoFrame(cols, rows, 'yuv422p')

with open('input.yuv422p', 'rb') as f:
    for n in range(n_frames):
        y = f.read(cols*rows)  # y = np.frombuffer(f.read(cols*rows), np.uint8).reshape(rows, cols)
        u = f.read(cols*rows//2)  # u = np.frombuffer(f.read(cols*rows//2), np.uint8).reshape(rows, cols//2)
        v = f.read(cols*rows//2)  # v = np.frombuffer(f.read(cols*rows//2), np.uint8).reshape(rows, cols//2)
        frame.planes[0].update(y)
        frame.planes[1].update(u)
        frame.planes[2].update(v)

        bgr_frame = frame.reformat(cols, rows, 'bgr24', src_colorspace='ITU709', dst_colorspace='DEFAULT', interpolation='BILINEAR')

        bgr = bgr_frame.to_ndarray()

        cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Notes:
Installing PyAV may be problematic (at least when using Windows).
Instead of using `pip install`, I downloaded a `whl` file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/av/#files) (and used `pip install` for installing the wheel).

I assumed that the YUV applies BT.709 standard (and applies "TV range" - `Y` range is [16, 235] not [0, 255]).
For correct conversion, you have to know the exacts standard of your raw data.